# Is there an algebraic topological way to characterise genus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

What I mean is, I know that the following representations are isomorphic to Torus and Torus with two 'holes' respectively:

$\pi_1(T_1) \cong\; \langle a,b\,|\; aba^{-1}b^{-1} \rangle$

$\pi_1(T_2) \cong\ \langle a,b,c,d\;|\;aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1} \rangle.$

Is there a way to determine the genus of surface based on these relators? I.e, say I have representation $\langle a,b,c\,|\; aba^{-1}b^{-1}, c^3,a^2,\ldots \rangle$, then does it immediately follow that it is some sort of genus-one surface?

Comment: Do you mean if you have a presentation of a group $G$, _and you know it's the fundamental group of a surface_, is there a way to compute the genus of the surface from the presentation? Or do you want to define a kind of "genus" for all finitely generated groups which happens to coincide with the topological genus in case $G$ is a surface group?

Comment: Do you know how to compute abelianization of a group from the given presentation? Do you know how to compute genus using rank of the 1st homology group?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor The latter. Without having knowledge that it's the fundamental group of a surface, i.e. I have bunch of relators, but one of them is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, and it happens that the representation is fundamental group of some surface.

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, It's my first course in Algebraic topology and we covered only some of homotopy, representations and covering spaces.

Comment: Then you are not ready for an answer to your question.